# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/CharArraySet

Tags: java, playframework, lucene

I'm running a play project on my machine and when I launch it, and used it through another web-server (send/receive request) I got the following exception. I already added lucene 6 jar files to lib directory, but not sure what causes this exception?

- lucene-analyzer-common
- lucene-core
- lucene-highlighter
- lucene-memory
- lucene-queryparser

  Any hints?

  ```
  a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/CharArraySet
      at artest.engine.common.ArabicAnalyzerFactory.getStemmingArabicAnalyzer(ArabicAnalyzerFactory.java:67)
      at engine.AbstractSearcher.<init>(AbstractSearcher.java:116)
      at engine.DocumentsSearcher.<init>(DocumentsSearcher.java:53)
      at engine.SearcherFactory.getSearcher(SearcherFactory.java:34)
      at controllers.SearchersFactory.<clinit>(SearchersFactory.java:30)
      at controllers.DocumentsController.search(DocumentsController.java:226)
      at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:193)
      at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:193)
      at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
      at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      at artest.engine.common.ArabicAnalyzerFactory.getStemmingArabicAnalyzer(ArabicAnalyzerFactory.java:67)
      at engine.AbstractSearcher.<init>(AbstractSearcher.java:116)
      at engine.DocumentsSearcher.<init>(DocumentsSearcher.java:53)
      at engine.SearcherFactory.getSearcher(SearcherFactory.java:34)
      at controllers.SearchersFactory.<clinit>(SearchersFactory.java:30)
      at controllers.DocumentsController.search(DocumentsController.java:226)
      at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:193)
  ```

Comment: Which version of lucene and play are you using? Are you placing those jars in a `lib` folder in your project root?

Comment: Yes I'm placing them in the lib directory in my root! Lucene6.2.0 and play2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Probably Lucene library is colliding with previous version library jars 
  Check if you are using multiple versions on deploying environment.
- Or May be you are using wrong version of Lucene library.

Comment: I had Lucene 5 and replaced it with Lucene 6. How to clean the project in such case because I already deleted all jar for Lucene 5 and I'm still getting this exception.

Comment: Look at in all other third party libraries that you are using, those might have already included Lucene library with those libraries. I'm pretty sure, these kind of exceptions with library conflicts.